# Refresh background pages using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

**Scenario :**

- Working on an e-commerce website.
- I have put together a **function which** :

  - updates the total number of
    items in the basket icon, and
  - also adjusts it when the user increases
    or decreases the qty amount for an item in the actual basket page.
  - I am using local storage to fetch and update the information.

- This particular basket page opens up in a new window. The basket icon is shown in pretty much all other pages of the website.

**Problem :**

- Even if the user has another page open in the background, I want that page to also refresh to reflect the new qty amount displayed in the basket icon, the second they adjusts the qty amount from the basket page.
- When the user closes the basket page and wants to continue
  shopping, the original page - prior to opening the basket page - has
  the updated number of items in the basket icon.
- There are three ways a user can adjust the number of items in the basket. Each product has an increase / decrease button, and also an input field where the user can enter a number manually and the basket qty icon will reflect the new change.

> Following function will change the qty of the item when user clicks either increase or decrease symbol

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var reg = /\w{7}\d+/g;
    if (e.target.classList[0] === "increaseQty") {
        var getItem = getLocalStorageData("basketData");
        getItem.basketQty++;
        document.getElementById("item-count").innerHTML = getItem.basketQty;
        e.target.previousSibling.value++;
        var currentProduct = e.target.previousSibling.id;
        currentProduct = currentProduct.match(reg);
        currentProduct = currentProduct.toString();
        getItem[currentProduct]++;
        updateLocalStorage(getItem);
        for (var i = 0; i < productCats.length; i++) {
            if (productCats[i][currentProduct]) {
                var currentPrice = e.target.previousSibling.value * productCats[i][currentProduct].price;
                var currentLi = e.target.parentNode;
                currentLi.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML = "£" + currentPrice;
                getTotalCost();
            }
        }
    } else if (e.target.classList[0] === "decreaseQty") {
        if (e.target.nextSibling.value > 0)
            var getItem = getLocalStorageData("basketData");
        getItem.basketQty--;
        document.getElementById("item-count").innerHTML = getItem.basketQty;
        e.target.nextSibling.value--;
        var currentProduct = e.target.nextSibling.id;
        currentProduct = currentProduct.match(reg);
        currentProduct = currentProduct.toString();
        getItem[currentProduct]--;
        updateLocalStorage(getItem);
        for (var i = 0; i < productCats.length; i++) {
            if (productCats[i][currentProduct]) {
                var currentPrice = e.target.nextSibling.value * productCats[i][currentProduct].price;
                var currentLi = e.target.parentNode;
                currentLi.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML = "£" + currentPrice;
                getTotalCost();
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
})

$("#basket-content").on("change", 'input[name="nameQty"]', function() {
    var getItem = getLocalStorageData("basketData");
    var regNum = /\d+/;
    var currentQty = this.id;
    var currentVal = this.value;
    var reg = /\w{7}\d+/g;
    var product = currentQty.match(reg);
    product = product.toString();
    if (!regNum.test(currentVal) || currentVal < 0) {
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
        document.getElementById(currentQty).value = getItem[product];
        return;
    } else if (currentVal > getItem[product]) {
        var addQty = currentVal - getItem[product];
        getItem.basketQty += addQty;
        document.getElementById("item-count").innerHTML = getItem.basketQty;
        getItem[product] = currentVal;
    } else if (currentVal < getItem[product]) {
        var minusQty = getItem[product] - currentVal;
        getItem.basketQty -= minusQty;
        document.getElementById("item-count").innerHTML = getItem.basketQty;
        getItem[product] = currentVal;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < productCats.length; i++) {
        if (productCats[i][product]) {
            var currentPrice = currentVal * productCats[i][product].price;
            document.getElementById(currentQty).parentNode.nextSibling.innerText = "£" + currentPrice.toFixed(2);
            getTotalCost();
        }
    }
    updateLocalStorage(getItem);
});
```

Comment: You could poll for changes in the basket. If the information is stored in local storage, those other pages can poll local storage for changes. You could even store a timestamp of the last change, so each page can simply check if the timestamp has changed compared to the one they previously loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the response Golez. If possible, please can you provide a solution with the best way to code this sort of thing?

Comment: I'd probably simply use `setInterval` for the polling. You already seem to know how to work with the local storage, so there you go.

Comment: Or use `postMessage` instead, and have your cart “notify“ all other open tabs when something changes.